# Using JSF 2.2.9 on Spring+Tomcat causes java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/enterprise/context/spi/Contextual

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, cdi

I need to use custom html attributes inside JSF components, and for this the only solution that i found is use JSF 2.2, in this way:

```
<f:passThroughAttribute name="data-toggle" value="modal" />
```

The problem is that i'm using Spring + Tomcat and i can't change this because i don't have time. Every time that i start my server i got the following error :

```
Informações: CDI @ViewScoped manager unavailable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/enterprise/context/spi/Contextual
```

I know this happens because i don't use CDI, but as i said i can't change from Spring to CDI because of time.

How can i solve this problem ? I must use JSF 2.2 (Because custom html attributes) and Spring.

**SOLVED:**

This problem as solved, i downgrade to JSF 2.2.6 and error stops.

**Stack trace:**

```
Fev 01, 2015 4:13:57 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeManager <init>
Informações: CDI @ViewScoped manager unavailable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/enterprise/context/spi/Contextual
at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeManager.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewScopeEventListener.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.getViewMap(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.getViewMap(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager$ScopeManager$ViewScopeHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager$ScopeManager.pushToScope(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:71)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.get(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.el.CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver$ExpressionEvalMap.get(Unknown Source)
at javax.el.MapELResolver.getValue(MapELResolver.java:52)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeValueExpression.getValue(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponentApplyAnnotations(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.createComponent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.composite.ImplementationHandler.apply(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.applyCompositeComponent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.applyNextHandler(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:72)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at br.com.jwebbuild.filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:73)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.context.spi.Contextual
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
... 98 more
```

Comment: Please answer your own question instead of modifying the question. Later you can accept your own answer and it is clear for everyone that this problem is solved.

Comment: @BalusC i added the stack trace (edit peer reviewed) as he send it to me yesterday, he was using Mojarra 2.2.9 with Tomcat 7, the problem was also resolved when he changed the bean scope to sessionScoped (Mojarra 2.2.9) but he don't want to change the scope, so i thought maybe this issue is still present https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3400 and i asked him to go back to Mojarra 2.2.6.
I replied to your comment just to inform you that this issue wasn't maybe resolved on 2.2.9

Answer (score 21):

I have same problem and found your question on google (i use JSF 2.2.9), with the answer from hwellmann, i added these depency on pom.xml of my maven project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and problem solved, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Did you include the [`cdi-api.jar`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22javax.enterprise%22%20a%3A%22cdi-api%22) in your setup?

That doesn't mean you have to *use* CDI in your application, but the API classes have to be there to satisfy the dependencies of JSF.

Comment: not, as i said i just downgrade the version of jsf.

Comment: @hwellmann why adding CDI if we will not use it ?! and which JSF dependencies ?

Comment: @Tarik: So you can use a newer version of your JSF library with all kinds of fixes? Newer versions of Mojarra seem to scan all classes and hence needs all 'optional' dependencies to (even if they will not be used at runtime). PrimeFaces(Extensions) has comparable 'issues': http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=40960 and one other that I cannot find now.

Comment: @Kukeltje so adding CDI is only for optional dependencies as you said, and not a 'must' like hwellmann said

Comment: Including the 'api' is a must (cdi-api.jar, like @hwellmann said), to satisfy the runtime class scanning that mojarra seems to be doing in more recent versions. You do not need to add the implemenation classes if you do not use it runtime. For PrimeFaces e.g. there are no separate api jars for the barcode, qr, poi, so you unfortunately need to include the full jars even if you do not use them. If this mojara behaviour stays like it is, component sets like PF will might split up in 'core' components and optional components. But it might even be that this scanning is configurable in mojarra.

Comment: @ Kukeltje sorry, but this doesn't make sense to me, if i understand well what you just said, we can't run JSF applications without adding cdi-api.jar ?! there is any spec talking about that ?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are using the `@ViewScoped` from `javax.faces.bean`, it was added in JSF 2.0. Try using the annotation from `javax.faces.view`, added in JSF 2.2.

Answer (score -1):

use JSF 2.2.8 or change tomcat to Apache TomEE, or configure CDI+JSF-Tomcat.
Best solution using jsf older versions because in the new versions will dependency from CDI